# Hiding tree nodes from the Git Repositories view

Tags: rcp, egit

I am including the EGit plug-in as part of an RCP application I am developing. However, I would like to hide some parts of the EGit UI.

The aspect I am looking at now is removing some nodes from the containment tree (implemented as a CommonViewer) displayed in the Git Repositories view. By default, every repository shown in this view has the "Tags" and "References" sub-nodes. How could I prevent these nodes from being shown?

I had some success hiding other UI elements using Activities, but I think this approach does not work in this case (Activities can only hide UI elements with unique IDs declared in a plugin.xml file).

Another approach I have looked into is programmatically adding a ViewerFilter to the CommonViewer. However, it seems this will only allow me to filter an entire repository from the view, not the sub-nodes displayed for each repository.